# How do I connect to a Custom Botconnector/ChannelAccount?

Tags: botframework, botconnector, direct-line-botframework

When using the Bot Framework, we would like to connect to one of our customer messaging interfaces. Currently, the online platform allows for connections to Skype, twilio, iFrame, etc.

We are attempting create a custom interface (through an API we control), we are not sure the best approach to achieve this. The REST API makes references to a "ChannelAccount", but does not go into detail as to how to get/set these.

Can we post messages directly (incoming), and set a callback URL (for outgoing), and then take care of the delivery/reception ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Direct Line API](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/#navtitle) to connect the bot to your custom client.
Also, see [this](http://docs.botframework.com/faq/#i-have-a-communication-channel-id-like-to-be-configurable-on-bot-connector-can-i-work-with-microsoft-to-do-that) in the FAQs.